# No network at 3rd stage of PXE Boot

Tags: ubuntu, networking, initramfs, broadcom, pxe

I try to boot with PXE an Ubuntu Image made from debootstrap on a Dell PowerEdge M610 with a Broadcom NetXtrem II (BCM 5709S) (bnx2 driver).

When i try to boot, everythings goes well at the bios stage, the machine got a DHCP Lease and Load File from TFTP Server.
When the INITRAMFS Boot, i load bnx2 driver, the interface goes up and load an IP Adresse from DHCP.
But when it try to load my squashfs over HTTP, the machine timeout, and after some check i can do anything on network (i can't ping 127.0.0.1 and the LAN IP of the Machine)

How can i repair this ?

For information :

- When i do an ipconfig of my network interfaces, the IP is set and the interface got few RX/TX Packets
- When i reload the bnx2 driver and setup the interface with **ip a** and **route**, i got a no route to host when i try get the squashfs

Thanks for you help

Comment: Please add the exact PXE commands you're using to load and boot the image to your question. My suspicion (from what details you've provided thus far) is that you're missing the `boot=live` argument in your APPEND statement or that your fetch command is incorrectly formatted. It should resemble this:

`KERNEL /foo/bar.vmlinuz`
`APPEND initrd=/foo/bar.initrd.img dhcp ethdevice=eth0 boot=live fetch=http://webserver/foo/bar.squashfs`